# Filter an Arraylist in different Arrays

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I want to filter a single array into parts. Suppose I have an `ArrayList` of String :

```
 Array1  = ["2015-01-06","2015-04-06",
    "2016-06-06","2016-01-06",
    "2016-05-06","2017-02-06",
    "2017-04-06","2017-03-06",
    "2015-03-06","2016-04-06",
    "2016-02-06","2015-05-06",
    "2015-01-06","2016-06-06"]
```

I want it to filter in new arrays according to their years, so that the output will look like :

```
arrayA = ["2015-01-06","2015-04-06","2015-03-06","2015-05-06","2015-01-06"]
arrayB = ["2016-06-06","2016-01-06","2016-05-06","2016-04-06","2016-02-06","2016-06-06"]
arrayC = [""2017-02-06","2017-04-06","2017-03-06""]
```

The arrays are based on years now. I don't know the proper way for accomplishing this task.

Comment: I´d use a `Map<String, String[]>` to represent the years.

Comment: hey @KevinEsche thanks a lot man for responding , yeah it'll be much better but am getting the in this pattern from my source

Comment: Why `Map<String, String[]>` instead of `Map<String, List<String>`?

Comment: You'd need to parse the individual array elements to some degree (if year is always 4 digit and at the start, a substring might suffice) and then add the element to a list. Use a map for the individual lists as already suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will create an ArrayList each year

```
ArrayList<String> array1 = new ArrayList<String>();
Map<String, List<String>> mapForYear = new TreeMap<String, List<String>>();
for(String date : array1)
{
    String year = date.substring(0,4);
    if(!mapForYear.containsKey(year))
        mapForYear.put(year, new ArrayList<String>());
    mapForYear.get(year).add(date);
}
```

Comment: as a suggestion better use HashMap instead of TreeMap :)

Comment: I've used TreeMap because this will garantee you that your Map is sorted by year. If you don't need that you can use HashMap as you want ;)

Answer (score 10):

*The question was edited to include the Android tag, making this inapplicable for the OP since Android doesn't support Java 8 yet, I'll leave it in case it helps someone not using Android though.*

---

Using the Stream API, you can easily build a `Map<Integer, List<String>>` where each key is a year. You can use [`groupingBy(classifier)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) where the classifier extracts the year from the date. In this case, the date is parsed with [`LocalDate.parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) but you could easily extend that by giving your own formatter.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] array = {"2015-01-06","2015-04-06",
                      "2016-06-06","2016-01-06",
                      "2016-05-06","2017-02-06",
                      "2017-04-06","2017-03-06",
                      "2015-03-06","2016-04-06",
                      "2016-02-06","2015-05-06",
                      "2015-01-06","2016-06-06"};

    Map<Integer, List<String>> map =
        Arrays.stream(array)
              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> LocalDate.parse(s).getYear()));
              // or a simple s -> Integer.valueOf(s.substring(0, s.indexOf('-'))) in this case
}
```

You can then access the list you want from that map.

Comment: hey @Tunaki thanks a lot for responding man , wasn't expected that much  fast and so many responses i tried your answer  and am getting some unresolved method exceptions in and in `Collectors` ,  `Arrays.stream` and in `index.of` i know that i have to use Stream API  but i never used it before i tried to find some getting started but didn't get what i'm expecting ? is it what i need for using Stream Api ? https://github.com/aNNiMON/Android-Java-8-Stream-Example

Comment: @remyboys It's an API that is included in Java 8. It's built-in, you don't need another library.

Comment: okay but i tried to rebuild my project so many times still android studio is not recognising it :( , and my java version  is already updated

Comment: but Android doesn't support Java 8, that's why you can't use it I suppose

Comment: @remyboys Android doesn't support Java 8 so, yes, it won't work. You should have added the android tag from the start. I edited to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

That's easy if you use java 8 and Stream API. I wrote the following piece of code:

```
public List<String> getListByYear(String[] array, int year) {
    return Arrays.stream(array)
                 .filter(s -> s.contains(Integer.toString(year)))
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

As to the question, there is such solution:

```
for (String s : array) {
    int key = LocalDate.parse(s).getYear();
    List<String> value = map.get(key);
    map.put(key, value == null
             ? new ArrayList<String>() { { add(s); } }
             : new ArrayList<String>(value) { { add(s); } }
    );
}
```

The same result as @Tunaki provided, but a less pretty. If Java 8 is not supported, it will be as the alternative as the most compact solution.

Output is here:

```
{
    2016 = [2016-06-06, 2016-01-06, 2016-05-06, 2016-04-06, 2016-02-06, 2016-06-06], 
    2017 = [2017-02-06, 2017-04-06, 2017-03-06],
    2015 = [2015-01-06, 2015-04-06, 2015-03-06, 2015-05-06, 2015-01-06]
}
```

Comment: Not sure how helpful this is. He doesn't want to specify a year - he wants to build a data structures that is already "sliced" for the different years.

Comment: @Jägermeister yeah man thats true , cause i can't predict the year it could be anything